# lsass.exe on Windows server listents port 5000. How to change this behaviour?

Tags: windows-server-2003

Our custom windows application listens on port 5000. After a regular reboot, our application could no longer listen on port 5000, since lsass.exe (Local Security Authentication Server) wich runs as a Windows Service already started listening on 5000. Is there a way to instruct lsass.exe not to use port 5000? Are there any other alternatives?

Comment: Configure your application to use another port.

Answer (score 2):

Your only chance is disabling the SSDP service on the server.  Note that you will lose functionality such as UPnP if you do this.

Otherwise, your only other option is to reconfigure your application to use another port.

Answer (score 1):

You can change dynamic port range used by Windows application by command:

```
netsh int ipv4 set dynamicport tcp start=<start_port> num=<ports_count>
```

see https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/929851/the-default-dynamic-port-range-for-tcp-ip-has-changed-in-windows-vista

Answer (score 0):

More than likely the default port range for your system has been altered from the standard 49152-65535 to the larger 1025-65535. This is done sometimes when certain applications are installed such as Microsoft Exchange or SQL Server.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3cd81773-e22c-4347-b10c-3dd2a8da6433/firewall-ports-for-remote-desktop-services-deployment?forum=winserverTS

> I'm running into this issue as well. On some systems the lsass, wininit, spoolsv, etc. are running on high ports (49152-65535) but on others they seem to be running on low ports 1024-5000. I'm not certain as to why the system is choosing which pool but it seems Microsoft has documented this behavior:
>
> https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/832017/service-overview-and-network-port-requirements-for-windows
>
> > Important This article contains several references to the default dynamic port range. In Windows Server 2008 and later versions, and in Windows Vista and later versions, the default dynamic port range changed to the following range:
> >
> > ```
> >    Start port: 49152
> >    End port: 65535
> > ```
> >
> > Windows 2000, Windows XP, and Windows Server 2003 use the following dynamic port range:
> >
> > ```
> >    Start port: 1025
> >    End port: 5000
> > ```
> >
> > What this means for you:
> >
> > ```
> >    If your computer network environment uses only Windows Server 2012, Windows Server 2008 R2, Windows Server 2008, Windows 8, Windows 7, or Windows Vista, you must enable connectivity over the high port range of 49152 through 65535.
> >     If your computer network environment uses Windows Server 2012, Windows Server 2008 R2, Windows Server 2008, Windows 8, Windows 7, or Windows Vista together with versions of Windows earlier than Windows Server 2008 and Windows Vista, you must enable connectivity over both the following port ranges:
> >         High port range 49152 through 65535
> >         Low port range 1025 through 5000
> >     If your computer network environment uses only versions of Windows earlier than Windows Server 2008 and Windows Vista, you must enable connectivity over the low port range of 1025 through 5000.
> > ```
> >
> > For more information about the default dynamic port range in Windows Server 2012, Windows 8, Windows Server 2008 R2, Windows 7, Windows Server 2008, and Windows Vista, click the followng article number to go to the article in the Microsoft Knowledge Base:
> >         929851 The default dynamic port range for TCP/IP has changed in Windows Vista and in Windows Server 2008
>
> In that last link there's another tidbit:
>
> > Note When you install Microsoft Exchange Server 2007 on a Windows Server 2008-based computer, the default port range is 1025 through 60000.
>
> For me, it seems to be related to SQL server. My guess is that systems with some enterprise grade software (exchange, SQL, etc.), the default port range gets increased from the standard 49152-65535 to a larger range (1025-60000?)
>
> This is supported by running the suggested commands
>
> ```
>    netsh int ipv4 show dynamicport tcp
>    netsh int ipv4 show dynamicport udp
>    netsh int ipv6 show dynamicport tcp
>    netsh int ipv6 show dynamicport udp
> ```
>
> I get back "start port 1025, Number of Ports 64510" on the systems using low ports and "Start port 49152, Number of ports 16384" on regular systems.
>
> They give commands to change the ports, though I don't know if there are consequences to changing it back when one of the special applications are running:
>
> ```
>    netsh int ipv4 set dynamicport tcp start=49152 num=16384
>    netsh int ipv4 set dynamicport udp start=49152 num=16384
>    netsh int ipv6 set dynamicport tcp start=49152 num=16384
>    netsh int ipv6 set dynamicport udp start=49152 num=16384
> ```